# Using the division operator in a query that gets data from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, database, subquery

I am having trouble writing a query that gets information from 3 different tables. Right now I have a query that runs... but I am not getting the right result. From talking to my peers I found out that one way to do this query would be to use the division operator but I am confused on how to do it. I will show you the query definition, the tables, and then the query that I wrote and maybe someone here can help me fix my query or explain to me how to utilize this division operator!

Query definition:

```
Find the users that utilize every protein in their jobs. 
So basically just find the users that have used every protein once. 
This could be within 1 job or 100 jobs.
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Job(uid INTEGER,job_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,input varchar(500),
FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES User(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY(job_id))ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Protein_Info(pid INTEGER,sequence varchar(200),
FOREIGN KEY(pid) REFERENCES Protein(pid),PRIMARY KEY(pid))ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Protein(pid INTEGER,name varchar(50),PRIMARY KEY(pid)) ENGINE=InnoDB;

insert into Job(uid, job_id, input) values(1, 1, abc),(2, 2, bce), (1, 3, aeo),(3, 4, pqo),(1, 5, bce), (1, 6, pqo)
insert into protein_info(pid, sequence) values (1,abc),(2,bce)(3,aeo),(4,pqo)
insert into protein(pid, name) values (1,a),(2,b),(3,c),(4,d)
```

So after these values are inserted.... I would want to retrieve information from user id 1 because he is the one that used all the proteins. I would want the output to be the user id and the count of jobs of a user that used all proteins. In this case it would be user id 1.

These two tables join on input and sequence. I join them when Job.input = Protein_Info.sequence.

The Query that I have tried.

```
SELECT u.uid, count(j.job_id) FROM Job j 
INNER JOIN Protein_Info p ON j.input = p.sequence 
GROUP BY j.job_id 
HAVING count(j.job_id) = (SELECT count(pid) FROM Protein);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a295d/3/0)

You were close:

```
SELECT j.uid, count(j.job_id) , count(distinct j.Input)
FROM Protein_info P 
INNER JOIN Job J
  ON j.input = p.sequence 
GROUP BY j.uid 
HAVING count(distinct j.Input) = (SELECT count(pid) FROM Protein);
```

What you had wrong was:

1. Group by needed to be by uID.
2. Having needed to count distinct `j.inputs` not the jobs.

Comment: May need to be careful with the inner join... something doesn't "feel" right there. data integrity may prevent eh issue giving me pause, but i'm not positive....

Answer (score 0):

This would work

```
Select u.uid from job u where u.input in(select sequence from protieninfo)
```